# How to use load time weaving without -javaagent?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, aspectj, load-time-weaving, compile-time-weaving

I am trying to enable loadtimeweaving without javaagent jar files of aspectweaver and spring-instrument. This what I have implemented to achieve the same But it's not working.

```
@ComponentScan("com.myapplication")
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableSpringConfigured
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving(aspectjWeaving = EnableLoadTimeWeaving.AspectJWeaving.AUTODETECT)
public class AopConfig implements LoadTimeWeavingConfigurer {
 
 @Override
 public LoadTimeWeaver getLoadTimeWeaver() {
     return new ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver();
 }
 
  /**
  * Makes the aspect a Spring bean, eligible for receiving autowired components.
  */
 @Bean
 public InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver loadTimeWeaver()  throws Throwable {
     InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver loadTimeWeaver = new InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver();
     return loadTimeWeaver;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A workaround I found was to hot-attach `InstrumentationSavingAgent` from `spring-instrument` instead of starting the agent via `-javaagent` command line parameter. But for that you need an `Instrumentation` instance. I just used the tiny helper library `byte-buddy-helper` (works independently of ByteBuddy, don't worry) which can do just that. Make sure that in Java 9+ JVMs the Attach API is activated if for some reason this is not working.

So get rid of `implements LoadTimeWeavingConfigurer` and the two factory methods in your configuration class and just do it like this:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
    <artifactId>byte-buddy-agent</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.14</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Instrumentation instrumentation = ByteBuddyAgent.install();
    InstrumentationSavingAgent.premain("", instrumentation);
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    // ...
  }
}
```

Feel free to ask follow-up questions if there is anything you do not understand.

---

**Update:** One more thing I noticed is that this only works for me with `aspectjWeaving = ENABLED`, not with `AUTODETECT`. And for one sample Spring bean I noticed that `@Component` did not work, probably because of some bootstrapping issue between Spring vs AspectJ. Hence, I replaced it by an explicit `@Bean` configuration, then it worked. Something like this:

```java
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.spring.aspect.dynamicflow")
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving(aspectjWeaving = ENABLED)
public class ApplicationConfig {
  @Bean
  public JobProcess jobProcess() {
    return new JobProcessImpl();
  }
}
```

---

**Update 2024-03-19:** If you are running your applications as **executable JARs on JRE 9+** (Spring Boot ones or other types), probably [Agent Embedder Maven Plugin](https://github.com/dev-aspectj/agent-embedder-maven-plugin?tab=readme-ov-file) is what you want.

It enables you to embed a java agent in your executable JAR and have it started automatically using the [`Launcher-Agent-Class` JVM mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html).

Unique features added by this plugin and unavailable via the original JVM mechanism: You can

- embed and run **multiple agents** (the JVM supports only one out of the box),
- pass an **option string** to each agent, just like from the JVM command line.

Spoiler: I am the author of the plugin and also happen to be the current maintainer of AspectJ.

P.S.: In the case of the AspectJ weaver, as the JVM starts the agent very early, weaving will be active without extra Spring configuration and it should work for all classloaders - no more `ClassLoader [...] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method` errors as seen when hot-attaching the weaver via `spring-instrument.jar`.